# How to export canvas to Png image and save it to gallery in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I created an application for image editing. I create some effected-on images from the gallery but can't save them after editing them.

This is an example of a canvas that I want to save as png.

```
    var resizedBitmap: Bitmap? = null
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(0.75f)) {
        val canvasWidth = size.width
        val canvasHeight = size.height
        with(painter) {
            draw(painter.intrinsicSize)
        }
        drawRect(black, size = size.copy(width = size.width / 2))
        drawRect(
            white,
            size = size.copy(width = size.width / 2),
            topLeft = Offset(x = size.width / 2F, y = 0F),
        )
        resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
            bitmap, (canvasWidth * 0.8).toInt(),
            (canvasHeight * 0.8).toInt(), true
        )
        drawImage(
            image = resizedBitmap!!.asImageBitmap(),
            dstOffset = IntOffset(
                x = (canvasWidth / 2).toInt() - (resizedBitmap!!.width / 2),
                y = (canvasHeight / 2).toInt() - (resizedBitmap!!.height / 2),
            ),

            )

    }
```

Comment: There are multiple libraries for capturing a composable as a bitmap, including https://github.com/PatilShreyas/Capturable, https://github.com/KaustubhPatange/kapture, and https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Screenshot.

Comment: @CommonsWare - How to use compose canvas in widget remoteview?